# Change the name of Server console

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Is there a way to change the name Server to something else, so when I announce something from the server console it could be from a name rather than just Server e.g.
this - [God] hello world.
instead of this - [Server] hello world.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

The first and easier option would be to summon an armorstand at spawn in the permanently loaded chunk named "God".

```
summon armor_stand X Y Z {Marker:1b,CustomName:'{"text":"God"}'}
```

You can then use it to announce stuff:

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,name=God,limit=1] run say Hello world
-> [God] Hello World
```

The second option is to use [`tellraw`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/tellraw). This is a bit more advanced, but I would suggest using it. It doesn't require an entity and is thus more fail save. It is also good practice to avoid using `say`.

```
tellraw @a {"text":"[God] Hello world"}
=> [God] Hello World
```

This also allows you to customize the output. For example to make "[God]" bold and dark red:

```
tellraw @a [{"text":""},{"text":"[God]","color":"dark_red","bold":true},{"text":" Hello world"}]
```